# How can I create a dynamic background with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a question: is it possible to exchange background according to one condition? Example:

```js
function A() {
  if (meuArray.length === 7) {
    i want background green
  } else {
    background blue
  }
}
```

At first I'm doing a card game called Black Jack or 21 in Brazil, and so far I have not found a viable form of background or a CSS in the array that contains the values of each card.

Would anyone have a tip or how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can. Just get the id of the dom and use this code. `document.getElementById('iwantgreen').style.backgroundColor = "green";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using JavaScript. Suppose you want to change the background of the element having id="demo"

then you can code it something like this:

```
if (meuArray.length === 7) {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "green";
} 
else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

if your want to select a class use:

```
    document.getElementsByClassName("demo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the dom using `document.getElementById` and set the `backgroundColor`

```
function A() {
      if (meuArray.length === 7) {
        document.getElementById('domId').style.backgroundColor = 'green'
      } else {
        document.getElementById('domId').style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
      }
    }
```